# VideoJS progress event always 0 on Safari 5.1

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari, video.js

I'm having this weird behaviour on Safari 5.1, while playing a video with VideoJS:

if I listen to the progress event:

```
var player = videojs('player_id', { 
    preload: 'auto'
    techOrder: [ 'html5' ]
});

player.on( 'progress', on_progress );

player.ready( function() { player.play() } );
```

I will only get value 0 in the callback:

```
function on_progress( event ) {
    console.log( 'buffered', player.bufferedPercent() );
    // it will log always 0
}
```

Notes:

- I can use only html5 player
- I'm using mp4/h264 videos with fallback to webm and ogv
- The code works on Chrome, Firefox and latest Safari

Any ideas?

Comment: The code above (with a minor fix to add a comma) works just fine for me in Safari. Here's a working [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/OlaquFe/1/edit).

Comment: Sorry @MattMcClure, I forgot to mention the Safari version: it's the 5.1. And your example is not working at all in that browser. Unfortunately I need to make it work even for that old version.

Comment: I commented on the answer you posted below, but you're out of luck for Safari for Windows :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've tried several video players and it looks like no one supports Safari 5.1.

These are the libraries i've tried with no luck:

http://www.videojs.com/

http://www.jwplayer.com/

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-video/

http://flowplayer.org/

http://www.projekktor.com/

Even http://caniuse.com/#search=video says Safari 5.1 supports html5 videos but the reality is IT DOESN'T.

Comment: Are you referring to Safari 5.1 for Windows? This is a known issue (incredibly frustrating, I know), but the good news is that Safari for Windows is a dead project and the usage numbers are tiny and dwindling.

Comment: @MattMcClure no unfortunately i'm talking about Safari 5.1 for OSX. Not working even there