# Iphone Safari browser: VideoJS is not triggering the progress event

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-safari, video.js

I'm trying to capture the "progress" event of the video element on iPhone's Safari but no event gets captured.

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G34 Safari/601.1" = $1
```

I found an related issue here: [VideoJS progress event always 0 on Safari 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456280/videojs-progress-event-always-0-on-safari-5-1)

On the bright side, I can capture the progress events on the Safari desktop.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Mobile Safari doesn't preload any video data if you set the Preload attribute on the video element. Hope that helps. =)